# Tracking Dojo UI Events

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is it possible to have a 'register a third party' function or modify the Dojo code base to  call my function each time Dojo processes a UI event?  In other words, I would like my own function to be called each time Dojo processes an event; and have the event object passed to my function so I can track all the user activity on the page.
Thanks
Jerry

Comment: You can use `dojo.connect` (or `dojo.on` in 1.7 and later) to hook up your handler with either DOM events or Dojo event raised by the widget.  In addition, each widget contains a `watch` function that allows you to add a "watch" handler to track property changes.  Or, as a last resort, "hijack" the event function in the object itself.  It is unlikely you'd need to modify Dojo sources.

Comment: The fact that you ask this question and that you think modifying the Dojo source is necessary indicates that you are probably new to JavaScript from a C-like language (e.g. C# or Java).  There are a lot of aspect-oriented-programming tricks possible with standard JavaScript that will be difficult to other languages without modifying the library source.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but the reason I feel I need to modify the codebase is described in my comment below.

Comment: my opinion is that the bubbling has nothing to do with your ability to trap the event.  Cancelable bubbling only prevents you catching the event if you put your handler higher than the widget.  If you hook your handler directly on the DOM node or the widget itself, then you'll always catch it.

Answer (score 0):

If you by 'UI event' mean DOM event then you can listen to window document object - `dojo.doc`  - as events bubble (as long as bubbling is not stopped, e.g. by `dojo.stopEvent(event)`):

```
dojo.connect(dojo.doc, "onclick", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Touch it at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/MJNh6/).

You may also consider to look at [dojox.form.Manager Tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/form_manager/) to observe form elements.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, using the dojo.connect approach was my first attempt, but since the bubbling up of the event can be stopped using dojo.stopEvent means there will be events that would be missed by my tracking code. Since I cannot have missing events the only other solution I could think of was to put my tracking function call within the dojo event handling process. So I was hoping there was someone who could point me in the right direction on were to start looking in the dojo codebase where I could put my tracking function call. Thanks again for all your time.

Comment: Try google 'website heatmaps' to find out what tricks to use. I am sure there are open source projects to study source code.